# calling polymer function from android webview

Tags: javascript, polymer, android-webview, polymer-1.0

I am working on building some pages in polymer to use in android web view.

**demo code below**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

        <dom-module id="trail-app">
            <template>
                <style>
                </style>

                <div id="content"></div>

            </template>

            <script>
                 Polymer({
                 is: "trail-app",

                 loadDataOne:function(data){
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data;
                 },

                 });
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                function loadDataTwo(data) {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data;
                }

            </script>   
        </dom-module>
        <trail-app></trail-app>
 </body>
</html>
```

So my problem here is if the function `loadDataTwo` is called like this `myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:loadDataTwo('Hello World!')");` it is working fine.
But if the function `loadDataOne` is called same way its not working.How to resolve.

Comment: That is because `loadOne` is a function defined inside `trial-app`. In order to call loadOne you need to select `trial-app` and then call `loadOne` on it.

Comment: if I do `var temp = document.querySelector('trail-app'); temp.loadDataOne()` it works.Should I select trail-app in android webview?

Comment: Yes, because `loadOne` is a function of `trail-app` element

Comment: i have posted solution below.Thank you @a1626 for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var temp = document.querySelector('trail-app');temp.loadDataOne('Hello World!')");` it worked fine.